# Benefits from event-based relationship rolls

Tags: 13th-age

Icon relationship dice are a bit confusing to me. I think I have a good handle on story-guide rolls but "dramatic events" less so. At first I thought they used the same rewards (like magic items, secret information, plot progression) as story-guide rolls, but now I'm reading it again and I'm seeing an alternate interpretation that instead they can be used to resolve events entirely as opposed to rolling/roleplaying them as they develop.

It's also possible both of my readings are wrong! Either way I'd appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1):

The main crux of GM-ing *13th Age* is figuring out how **you** want to do Icon rolls.

Some use them for item distribution, others as a "get out of jail free" card, and others use them as general story guides.

These are based on how much weight you want to assign these singular die rolls. Each has its own merits.

While theoretically evenly distributed, we all have experienced those players with atrocious luck on a single type of roll. Therefore, I usually use them as general story guides in the abstract. Allegiances of an upcoming NPC, or the aesthetics of a magic item. I also use them on an individual basis for certain knowledge rolls tied to that Icon.

Now, that's not to say that my way is the "right" or "standard" way. This is what works for me and my imaginary table (I tend to play online). Your milage may vary.

Comment: I understand that, I'm asking about the difference between story guide rolls and dramatic event rolls.